# Jconsole and Java Connection Failed Error Windows 7 Java 8

Tags: java, jconsole

Jconsole showing process list, but it is giving "Connection failed: Retry" on trying to analyse application ?

Comment: have you tried with JVisualVM to connect to the processes as well?

Comment: Could you copy the hole Exception shown on jconsole?

Comment: check if your server have stopped/terminated

Comment: I am trying to see my local application. It is appearing in jconsole, but when i am connecting it, it is giving error. Firstly, it is giving popup saying : Secure Connection failed : Retry Unsecurely ?.......  When I click on Insecure connection button, than after some time another pop up comes saying : Connection Failed : Retry ? The connection to 2343 did not succeed. Would you like to try again.

Comment: JVisualVM is connecting to process, but it is not showing CPU status

Comment: @Jan, thanx for replying, any guess further..

Comment: @ikken , thanx for replying, any guess further

Comment: @Arivazhagan Jeganathan ,thanx for replying, any guess further

Comment: Could anyone look and  help ..?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the remote  JMX agent is expecting SSL connection by default.

Add these 2 parameters whene lunching your JAVA application

```
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```